# Cursor moves to end of the contenteditable div when character removed from div

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

I am working on creating my own chat application in which I used content-editable `div` as chatbox.
I am implementing mention feature where my mention is username wrapped in a span tag followed by a space(`&nbsp;`) but my problem is when I remove space my cursor moves to the end of the div.

with space

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable=true><span contenteditable='false'>UserName</span>&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

without space

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable=true><span contenteditable='false'>UserName</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is how I implemented in code and also this bug happens only in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Analysis

Think of a simple text editor(notepad) where you have typed three characters - `TRY`

Now, its obvious that the cursor can be placed only at 4 places here, which are:

- before T
- between T and R
- between R and Y
- after Y

The reason for which is simply because, these 3 characters are the only **editable** ones here and they are 3 individual entities, which can't be edited/separated further. For example, we can't place the cursor in between the letter 'T' and separate the `┐` and `┌` from it.

Same is the case with your scenario as the cursor is moved to the end of the div once the `&nbsp;` is cleared because the `contenteditable=true` is set to the `<div>` and is set as `false` to the `<span>`. Therefore the `div` is the only editable element here and the `span` is not. So the cursor can position itself only on an editable place which is either at the beginning of an editable element(`div` in this case) or at the end of it and **not** in between.

As the `div` is a block element, the cursor is moved to the end of the page as the block elements occupy the whole width of its parent. We can see the cursor being moved to the middle of the page if we set `width: 50%;` to the `div`.

### Solution

Considering your comments on other answers, that you need to keep the width as `100%`, the solution is to wrap the `div` with another one which also have the attribute `contenteditable=true` and keep the child `div` as an `inline-block` element.

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <div class="inl-blck" contenteditable=true><span contenteditable='false'>UserName</span>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/qoabaZ)

### Explanation

Here, both the parent and child `div`s are editable where the parent occupying the full width (100%) and the child is an `inline-block` element, which just occupies the space of its contents. Therefore, once the `&nbsp;` is cleared, the cursor moves to the end of the next editable content which is the child `div`.

Note that, you need to keep the child `div` and `span` along with the `&nbsp;` in the same line in you code as otherwise it will create extra characters (whitespaces) in the section, which will break the `contenteditable` further.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nicely done. In my answer, I just misplaced the `&nbsp;`. LOL, thank you for the clarification bro. :) the bounty is yours to keep.

Comment: Thank you. Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 8):

This is actually *a bug in the browsers*, I have a **workaround** but I don't know how much it will help you but this is the best we can do now in my knowledge.

```css
div>span {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false">UserName</span></span>&nbsp;</div>
```

Without space

```css
div>span {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false">UserName</span></span></div>
```

If you want a ***full proof content*** to be there then here is a solution with `script` combining `: before` pseudo:

Here am taking the width of the `: before` pseudo-element and hading it over to the `div` element `padding-left`. I have used script keeping in mind of your dynamic usernames.

```js
var testBox = document.querySelector('.test'),
  pseudoBeforeWidth = window.getComputedStyle(testBox, ':before').width, //getting the width of the parent elemnts `:before`
  pseudoBeforeContent = window.getComputedStyle(testBox, ':before').content;

testBox.style.paddingLeft = pseudoBeforeWidth; //handing the width to the parent elemnts padding left style
var i = 0
var n = 0;
testBox.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
  if ((key === "Backspace" || key === "Delete") && n == 0) {
    i++
    console.log(testBox.textContent, i, n);
    if (testBox.textContent == "" && i >= 2) {
      testBox.className += ' userhide ';
      testBox.style.paddingLeft = 0;
      n = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div:before {
  content: attr(data-user);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}

.test.userhide:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" contenteditable="true" data-user="UserName"></div>
```

I hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: It prevents the cursor from going to the end but I have to press backspace twice to remove it.

Comment: please test your code in the first code snippet(with space) it takes 2 backspaces to remove userName span

Comment: In first code snippet, 1 backspace is used to remove space and 2 backspaces to remove span total of 3 backspaces

Comment: My chrome version is also same but my code clears all content in only 2 backspaces

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I have updated the `javascript` code for your needed result so please do check if you are interested in `script` solution for this bug.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal there is an answer from *Gibin Ealias*, I think that is what you are looking for if it is please do mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This Can Help You

```
<div contenteditable=true style="display: inline-block;background: #000;color:#fff;"><span contenteditable=false>UserName</span>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Nope, my div width is set to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not this bug has to do with whitespace in the actual HTML markup itself.

Here is a working example:

```css
.username {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="false" class="username">Username</span>
</div>
```

By simply moving the closing div to the next line gives we communicate the break to the html parser.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but still, we need a space`&nbsp;` before *Username* by adding that to your answer the result becomes the same as the question bug.

Comment: Updated the snippet, use CSS to enforce spacing around the username.

Comment: *1 backspace is used to remove space and 2 backspaces to remove span* this is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to add `<br>` inside the contenteditable block.

```
<body>
  <div contenteditable=true><span contenteditable='false'>UserName</span>&nbsp;<br></div>
</body>
```